# Understanding ruby blocks

Tags: ruby, block

What is a good conceptual way to look at Ruby blocks?

if I have an Array, A, and I pass it to the following function:

```
def MergeSort(&var)
...
end
```

And then run the function, passing an Array into it:

```
MergeSort(A)
```

Will the array A be treated like a block in the function? What is the benefit of blocks, and what are good patterns to use them in? I realize these are kind of unrelated and potentially random questions; any answer that clarifies Ruby blocks would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Understanding Ruby Blocks, Procs and Lambdas by Robert Sosinski](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) explains it very thoroughly.

Comment: That is a dead link now, for any future search you might want to check this [one](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) instead

Comment: @IslamAzab, thanks. I updated the link. I guess this shows the problem with link-only answers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this article http://blog.codahale.com/2005/11/24/a-ruby-howto-writing-a-method-that-uses-code-blocks/. I recommend you to read it carefully to fully understand blocks in ruby.

Comment: Thanks @negarnil, I shall check that out soon